# Can you mount an AWS Multi-Attach EBS volume to an auto-scaling group in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ebs, aws-auto-scaling

I have created an **EBS** volume that I can attach to **EC2** instances using Terraform, but I cannot work out how to get the EBS to connect to an EC2 created by an autoscaling group.

Code that works:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_name" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.name.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.server.id
}
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_name" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.name.id
  instance_id = aws_launch_template.asg-nginx.id
}
```

What I am hoping for is an auto-scaling launch template that adds an EBS that already exists, allowing for a high-performance EBS share instead of a *"we told you not to put code on there"* EFS share.

**Edit:** I am using a multi-attach **EBS**. I can attach it manually to multiple **ASG**-created **EC2** instances and it works. I just can't do it using Terraform.

**Edit 2:** I finally settled on a `user_data` entry in **Terraform** that ran an **AWS** command line bash script to attach the multi-attach EBS.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
[…aws keys here…]
aws ec2 attach-volume --device /dev/sdxx --instance-id `cat /var/lib/cloud/data/instance-id` --volume-id vol-01234567890abc
reboot
```

**Terraform:**

```
data "template_file" "shell-script" {
  template = file("path/to/script.sh")
}
data "template_cloudinit_config" "script_sh" {
  gzip = false
  base64_encode = true
  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = data.template_file.shell-script.rendered
  }
}
resource "aws_launch_template" "template_name" {
  […]
  user_data = data.template_cloudinit_config.mount_sh.rendered
  […]
}
```

The risk here is storing a user's AWS keys in a script, but as the script is never stored on the servers, it's no big deal. Anyone with access to the `user_data` already has access to better keys than the one you're using here keys.

Comment: This doesn't work. If it did work, what would you expect to happen if the ASG cycled out the instance? You can run stateful applications in an ASG, but I would not try reusing EBS volumes

Comment: I am using a Multi-Attach EBS that's designed to be attached to multiple EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

This would require Terraform being executed every time a new instance is created as part of a scaling event, which would require automation to invoke.

Instead you should look at adding a [lifecycle hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) for your autoscaling group.

You could configure the topic to [trigger an SNS notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/configuring-lifecycle-hook-notifications.html#sns-notifications) that invokes a [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) function to attach to your new instance.

Comment: This looks like the only way that will work. It's a shame several pages of Terraform and about a dozen resources are needed instead of just one line in an ASG resource, but that's life. I suspect this is because attaching EBS volumes is done from the EBS, not the EC2.